# Cross tables in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have these two tables

ItemMov

```
Item  Date
A     2018-03-31
A     2018-03-30
A     2018-03-25
B     2018-03-28
B     2018-03-29
```

and DateTable

```
Date
2018-03-31
2018-03-30
2018-03-29
2018-03-28
2018-03-27
2018-03-26
2018-03-25
```

What i need is to have a sort of cross product between those two but limited to the earlest date for each item.
Initially i used simple cross product.

```
select distinct t.Item, f.Date from ItemMov t cross join DateTable f
```

getting this

```
Item       Date
 A    2018-03-31
 A    2018-03-30
 A    2018-03-29
 A    2018-03-28
 A    2018-03-27
 A    2018-03-26
 A    2018-03-25
 B    2018-03-31
 B    2018-03-30
 B    2018-03-29
 B    2018-03-28
 B    2018-03-27
 B    2018-03-26
 B    2018-03-25
```

Of course this crossing brings dates early than the first date for some items, like B.
The desired output should be something like that but limited to the min(date) for each item. So, is there a why of doing this with crossing tables or should a use some sort of loop?

Desired output

```
Item       Date
 A    2018-03-31
 A    2018-03-30
 A    2018-03-29
 A    2018-03-28
 A    2018-03-27
 A    2018-03-26
 A    2018-03-25
 B    2018-03-31
 B    2018-03-30
 B    2018-03-29
 B    2018-03-28
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those extra parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply do `select distinct t.Item, f.Date ...`.

Comment: I don't understand the logic by which you arrive at your expected output.  Can you explain it better?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The idea is that every Item would have rows with dates from the first date in DateTable but limited the its earliest date from ItemMov table.

Comment: See if you like `SELECT i.Item, d.Date FROM DateTable d LEFT JOIN `ItemMov i USING(Date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a `join` with `on` clause date expression:

```
select distinct t.Item, f.Date 
from ItemMov t 
inner join DateTable f on t.Date <= f.Date
-- cross join DateTable f on t.Date <= f.Date
order by t.Item, f.Date desc
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/SKU45142)

Comment: So simple and it works. Isn't inner join supposed to bring only dates found in both tables? Crearly Items in ItemMov don't  have "movements" everyday.

Comment: Since the `on` clause does not use full equality, `=`, the `inner join` mimics `cross join` but with subset. In fact, you can use `cross join` in its place!

Comment: @BenJ. It's more clear to say inner join only returns rows for which the condition in the `ON` clause evaluates to TRUE. If you only use `=` as your condition, then yes, the value must be the same in both tables. But you can use any type of expression, not just `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate before doing a `join`:

```
select i.item, d.date
from (select i.item, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
      from itemmov i
      group by i.item
     ) i join
     datetable d
     on d.date >= i.min_date and d.date <= i.max_date
order by i.item, d.date;
```